# Review flag on main bar keeps showing, but there's nothing to review

Tags: discussion, bug

I keep seeing the little orange box in the main bar across the top of GD.SE indicating there are review flags.

[image]

Up until yesterday, I'd click this flag box, review the items, then the box would disappear.

However, it seems now the flag box is there for no reason. There's nothing to review when clicking it and it never goes away.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pearson is correct, but here is information from a MSO post reporting the same issue. This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) *[for now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230742/216955)*. The explanation from the devs is:

> Anna Lear responded, "Not bugged. The topbar count is every review in
>   the system, not just the ones available to you (ie ones you haven't
>   skipped or already otherwise acted on)." Shog9 says, "this is
>   everything in review, even stuff that you, personally, can't review.
>   Super-expensive to personalize this - so the alternative is simply not
>   having an indicator. Think of it as... A reminder to encourage your
>   peers to review." <sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-much#comment758043_230742)</sup>

Shog also pointed out that this only appears for those with access to the moderator tools (10k+ rep or a mod). There is a feature request opened up to change this behavior: [Modulate the review notification's color to reflect changes, or make it dismissible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230833/216955).

Comment: Okay... that makes sense. I guess i'm just accustomed to the flags I can't see being removed before I get to my flags :) Darn slow moderators :)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that it's including review items which are either skipped or already complete on your part, while it should just be showing the sum of your review items in the queue. Given that, I hope it's fixed soon!